# Zebra puzzle in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have attempted to a zebra puzzle in prolog and I was seeking some feedback as to the way I went about solving the puzzle.

Here is the puzzle:

> Two weeks ago, four enthusiasts made sightings of objects in the sky
>   in their    neighborhood. Each of the four reported his or her
>   sightings on a different day. The FBI came and was able to give each
>   person a different explanation of what he or she had "really" seen.
>   Can you determine the day (Tuesday through Friday) each person sighted
>   the object, as well as the object that it turned out to be?
>
> - Mr. K made his sighting at some point earlier in the week than the one who saw the balloon, but at some point later in the week, than the
>     one who spotted the Kite (who isn't Ms. G).
> - Friday's sighting was made by either Ms. Barn or the one who saw a plane (or both).
> - Mr. Nik did not make his sighting on Tuesday.
> - Mr. K isn't the one whose object turned out to be a telephone pole.

Here is a representation of how I found the solution to the problem:

I know K didn't spot the balloon (1) or the kite (2) or the telephone pole (6), so K spotted the plane. Also, K's day can't be Friday (1), so Friday was B's day (4).

I also know the kite wasn't spotted by K (2) or G (3). Nor was it spotted by B, since B's day was Friday and the kite can't have been spotted on Friday (2). So N spotted the kite. Also, we know kite day is two days before balloon day (1,2), so kite day must have been Tuesday or Wednesday; but N's day wasn't Tuesday (5), so kite day was Wednesday, which means K's day was Thursday (2) and balloon day was Friday (1).

And the rest I got by elimination. Summing up:

```
G spotted a telephone pole on Tuesday.
N spotted a kite on Wednesday.
K spotted a plane on Thursday.
B spotted a balloon on Friday.
```

And here is my prolog code:

```
before(X,Y,Ds) :-
    remainder(X,Ds,Rs),
    member(Y,Rs).

remainder(X,[X|Ds],Ds).
remainder(X,[_|Ds],Rs) :- remainder(X,Ds,Rs).

members([],_).
members([X|Xs],Ds) :-
member(X,Ds),
members(Xs,Ds).

puzzle :-
Days = [[tuesday,_,_],[wednesday,_,_],[thursday,_,_],[friday,_,_]],
before([_,mr_klien,_],[_,_,balloon],Days),
before([_,_,frisbee],[_,mr_klien,_],Days),
(member([friday,ms_barnum,_],Days);
    member([friday,_,clothesline],Days);
    member([friday,ms_barnum,clothesline],Days)),
members([[_,mr_klien,_],[_,ms_barnum,_],[_,ms_green,_],[_,mr_niven,_]],Days),
members([[_,_,balloon],[_,_,frisbee],[_,_,clothesline], [_,_,water_tower]],Days),
member([_,NOT_ms_green,frisbee],Days), NOT_ms_green \= ms_green,
member([tuesday,NOT_mr_niven,_],Days), NOT_mr_niven \= mr_niven,
member([_,NOT_mr_klien,water_tower],Days), NOT_mr_klien \= mr_klien,
write(Days),
nl,
fail.
```

Answer (score 2):

This is quite nice, but there are still several ways that would improve this.

Here are a  few ideas:

## Relations instead of side-effects

First, I recommend to **avoid side-effects**. Instead, think in terms of **relations**. By this I mean that you should not use `write/1` to print a solution, but express *what constitutes a solution*, as in the following:

```
solution(Days) :-
        Days = [[tuesday,_,_],[wednesday,_,_],[thursday,_,_],[friday,_,_]],
        etc.
```

Here, I have made `Days` available for reasoning as a **predicate argument**. This way, you can explicitly reason about solutions, and for example write actual *test cases* by stating what should and should not hold about *given* solutions. You *cannot* do this if the solution only occurs in the form of *output* on the system terminal.

If you need to *print* a solution in any way, you can use the more general form above to *still* do that. For example:

```
?- solution(Ds),
   maplist(writeln, Ds).
[tuesday,ms_green,water_tower]
[wednesday,mr_niven,frisbee]
[thursday,mr_klien,clothesline]
[friday,ms_barnum,balloon]
```

## Use higher-order predicates

Suppose I give you the following auxiliary predicate:

```
list_member(Ls, E) :- member(E, Ls).
```

Then you can use **`maplist/2`** to express `members/2` as follows:

```
members(Es, Ls) :- maplist(list_member(Ls), Es).
```

When you encounter predicates that reason over lists, check the available higher-order predicates (especially `maplist/N` and `foldl/N`) to see if they can simplify your code.

## Use dif/2 instead of `(\=)/2`

You are currently using the **impure** predicate `(\=)/2` in your code. This prevents you from using Prolog to its fullest potential.

Use `dif/2` instead to benefit from the declarative nature of true **relations**: You can then pull these goals towards the *beginning of the clause* or at least *earlier*, and benefit from their **pruning** in addition to the added flexibility of placing the goal anywhere you like in principle.

## Indentation

**Never** put `(;)/2` at the end of a line. It looks too similar to `(',')/2`, which *typically* occurs at that position.

In total, a solution could look like (in addition to the points mentioned previously):

```
solution(Days) :-
        Days = [[tuesday,_,_],[wednesday,_,_],[thursday,_,_],[friday,_,_]],
        before([_,mr_klien,_],[_,_,balloon],Days),
        before([_,_,frisbee],[_,mr_klien,_],Days),
        (   member([friday,ms_barnum,_],Days)
        ;   member([friday,_,clothesline],Days)
        ;   member([friday,ms_barnum,clothesline],Days)
        ),
        members([[_,mr_klien,_],[_,ms_barnum,_],[_,ms_green,_],[_,mr_niven,_]], Days),
        members([[_,_,balloon],[_,_,frisbee],[_,_,clothesline],[_,_,water_tower]], Days),
        dif(NOT_ms_green, ms_green),
        member([_,NOT_ms_green,frisbee],Days),
        dif(NOT_mr_niven, mr_niven),
        member([tuesday,NOT_mr_niven,_],Days),
        dif(NOT_mr_klien, mr_klien),
        member([_,NOT_mr_klien,water_tower],Days).
```

Now we can query:

```
?- solution(Ds).
Ds = [[tuesday, ms_green, water_tower], [wednesday, mr_niven, frisbee], [thursday, mr_klien, clothesline], [friday, ms_barnum, balloon]] ;
false.
```

And also ask something different, for example:

```
?- Ds = [[monday, ms_green|_]|_],
   solution(Ds).
false.
```

Thus, the system tells us: **No**, *that's* not a solution!

This is now easily possible because we can reason *explicitly* about solutions, having made them available as a predicate argument.

Answer (score 1):

On top of what mat mentioned, here are some general programming suggestions which also apply here:

#### Give names to data-structures.

You are using a list of lists to represent the solution. That's OK, but not every list of lists is of the shape of your solution.  Also, dealing with low-level representation of the data-structure makes you write a lot of unnecessary code (you are forced to write `_` many times, and it makes it harder to extract valuable information from the source code).

#### Give names to helper functions.

This makes it easier for humans to understand what your predicate is about.  Once it is entirely made of `member(X, L)`, it is hard to recognize common programming patterns s.a. filtering, searching, permuting etc.  Once you are able to organize low-level predicates into groups and name those groups, you have made it easier for the reader to understand your intention.

#### Exploit nondeterminism.

Prolog has a relatively unusual feature--it allows nondeterminism in your code.  It is a very powerful tool.  Consider `before(X, Y)` as a good candidate for nondeterminism since it is true of `X=wednesday, Y=thursday` and `X=wednesday, Y=friday`.

---

Below is an example which tries to illustrate the ideas mentioned above:

```
days([tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday]).

before(X, Y) :-
    days(Days),
    append([_, [X], After], Days),
    member(Y, After).

permute([], []).
permute([X | Xs], Ys) :-
    permute(Xs, Zs),
    select(X, Ys, Zs).

event_of([(Day, Event) | _], Event, Day) :- !.
event_of([(OtherDay, _) | Mappings], Event, Day) :-
    dif(Day, OtherDay),
    event_of(Mappings, Event, Day).

puzzle([
    spotted(mr_klien, KlienEvent, KlienDay),
    spotted(ms_green, GreenEvent, GreenDay),
    spotted(mr_niven, NivenEvent, NivenDay),
    spotted(ms_barnum, BarnumEvent, BarnumDay)]) :-
    days(Days),
    permute(Days, [KlienDay, GreenDay, NivenDay, BarnumDay]),
    permute(Days, [BaloonDay, KiteDay, PlaneDay, PhoneDay]),
    before(KlienDay, BaloonDay),
    before(KiteDay, KlienDay),
    dif(GreenDay, KiteDay),
    ( BarnumDay = friday ; PlaneDay = friday ),
    dif(NivenDay, tuesday),
    dif(PhoneDay, KlienDay),
    EventMapping = [
        (BaloonDay, baloon),
        (KiteDay, kite),
        (PlaneDay, plane),
        (PhoneDay, phone)
    ],
    maplist(event_of(EventMapping),
            [KlienEvent, GreenEvent, NivenEvent, BarnumEvent],
            [KlienDay, GreenDay, NivenDay, BarnumDay]).
```